# Login into Azure VM with credentials stored in Azure key vault

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am new azure cloud , i have totally 5 VM running in my Azure subscription. All of them have a separate login credentials(username & password) to login into specific VM.

Right now i stored all of those credentials in **excel file**.its not a secure way to keep those credentials.

I would like to use **Azure key vault** to store all credentials into centralised and secure location.

I can store my login credentials to **key vault** but i don't know how to use it while login into Azure VM.

I googled quite a lot but i could not found any solution.

can anyone help me to accomplish what i am looking for ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need a password manager, Key Vault isn't that in my opinion.

Comment: can't i able to use key vault to store my VM credentials and use URI of my credentials to login into VM ?

Comment: No, that's not possible

Comment: Unless you mean that you will write an app which reads this creds from KV and programmatically connects to the VM

Comment: Agree with juunas - key vault is more for keeping application secrets. This just sounds like you could use a password manager. You could store in key vault, but not quite sure how you’d access the secret to use to login without more or less just making a poor mans password Manager like Bitwarden

Comment: How do you login into the VM? Is the VM Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

For linux, you certainly can store your password in kv and use that as a variable in your pipeline or code. x = $(az keyvault secret show [--id] [--query] --output tsv)

Comment: Great suggestion. Thank you @MdaEngineer